# Play sound with SoundPool

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

I need to play a short sound in my application. I wrote the following code but I have no sound and strange vibration appeared on my Samsung phone. But in the same time this code works well on my android simulator. My code is:

```
package com.samplers;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FixVibroActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private Button white;
    private SoundPool spool;
    private int soundID;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        spool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        soundID = spool.load(this, R.raw.error, 1);

        white = (Button)findViewById(R.id.whiteBtn);
        white.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Sound();
            }
        });
    }

    public void Sound(){
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        float volume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        spool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
    };
}
```

Help me to solve this problem, please! Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Can you check if logcat prints any interesting errors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There might either be an issue with your volume control or with your sound file playing correctly: if you change the `Sound()` function to this what does it do? If your phone is not correctly handling the `R.raw.error` file format but the emulator is doing it correctly that would be VERY strange.

```
public void Sound(){
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        float volume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        android.util.Log.v("SOUND","["+volume+"]["+spool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f)+"]");
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay! The problem is solved! :) I changed file format from *.ogg to *.wav and bingo!!!! :) Thanks for help! :)

Comment: Ah, the phone doesn't support ogg but the emulator does. Good to know. Thought it might be the file format.

Comment: The phone supports this format. This file was played with MediaPlayer but only once and after that was silence. In any case good news for me :) Thanks again! :)

Comment: Ah, my mistake: SoundPool/Audiotrack require PCM data which is what a *wav* gives you. MediaPlayer does the decode for the *ogg* but SoundPool doesn't.

Comment: I see, now everything is clear!!! I'll take this info in account for my future work. Thanks. :)