# How to use SoundPool in class that extends Button?

Tags: java, android, button, soundpool

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Play sound with SoundPool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396711/play-sound-with-soundpool)

How do I set up SoundPool, I tried the usual way but no sound was played. There are no problems with the music file. I would like the Sound to play on Action_Down and stop at Action_up. Mediaplayer works, but the button responds with a delay.

```
package dubpad.brendan;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TestButton3 extends Button {
MediaPlayer mpButtonClick;


public TestButton3(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {




    }
    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396711/play-sound-with-soundpool-on-android

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tamir! But that doesn't help, that works only for a class that extends an activity, not a button.

Comment: @ChrisBrendan - it shouldn't matter if it's an activity or a button. If you pass the activity context to the button, you should be able to call any context-related methods from inside the button. Or why specifically do you think the linked answer isn't applicable?

Comment: I passed the activity context to the button, but it doesn't work. Anyway I got the solution, thanks a lot!

Comment: Chris, what do you mean "I got the solution"? Is the issue solved, and if it is, could you please post the solution as an answer?